# Insert prepare statement mutiple checkbox with multiple queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I know this question may have been asked before but I cannot find the solution for my issue. I want to implement prepare statements (procedural) to multiple checkbox I do understand how it works and has worked with it before. But in this situation, I am not sure how to implement it. Can someone please provide me with a clue?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
        $sql1="UPDATE switch SET status = 1 WHERE id = 1";
    } else {
        $sql1="UPDATE switch SET status = 0 WHERE id = 1";
    }
    $result=$conn->query($sql1);

    if (isset($_POST['checkbox2'])) {
        $sql2="UPDATE switch SET status = 1 WHERE id = 2";
    } else {
        $sql2="UPDATE switch SET status = 0 WHERE id = 2";
    }
    $result=$conn->query($sql2);

    if (isset($_POST['checkbox3'])) {
        $sql3="UPDATE switch SET status = 1 WHERE id = 3";
    } else {
        $sql3="UPDATE switch SET status = 0 WHERE id = 3";
    }
    $result=$conn->query($sql3);

    if (isset($_POST['checkbox4'])) {
        $sql4="UPDATE switch SET status = 1 WHERE id = 4";
    } else {
        $sql4="UPDATE switch SET status = 0 WHERE id = 4";
    }
    $result=$conn->query($sql4);
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" action="" method="POST" >

        <label>
            Checkbox 1
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit();"
                <?php if(isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        </label>

        <label>
            Checkbox 2
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="1" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit();"
                <?php if(isset($_POST['checkbox2'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        </label>

        <label>
            Checkbox 3
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="1" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit();"
                <?php if(isset($_POST['checkbox3'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        </label>

        <label>
            Checkbox 4
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="1" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit();"
                <?php if(isset($_POST['checkbox4'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        </label>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like a good opportunity to D.R.Y. out your code.  Even in its current state, you are repeating the whole sql when only a single character changes.  Maybe give yourself the mental challenge of doing this all in a single trip to the database.  In my own application, I'd go all the way back to the declaration of the checkbox names and use array syntax instead of appended numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I know its not the most elegant lines of code, but I want to understand how to implement prepare statement given in this situation. And later I will try to improve upon it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the form construction, you should not make `name` attributes with appended numbers when the data is more meaningfully established in an array structure.  By using arrays, multiple techniques can be implemented you make your code less bloated, hardcoded, and repetitious.  Perhaps for easier reading, rename your name attributes `boxes` instead of `checkbox` which is identical to the `type` attribute.

Use a loop to construct your fields.

```
$maxBoxes = 4;  // assign this near the top of your php file so that multiple sections of your file can use it.

$fieldTemplate = <<<HTML
<label>
    Checkbox %1$d
    <input type="checkbox" name="boxes[%1$d]" value="1"%2$s>
</label>

HTML;

for ($x = 1; $x <= $maxBoxes; ++$x) {
    printf(
        $fieldTemplate,
        $x,  // %1$d
        isset($_POST['boxes'][$x]) ? " checked" : '' // %2$s
    );
}
```

Move your `onchange` inline event to the `<head>` of your HTML document or better yet, into an external .js file.  This keeps your HTML markup very clean, lean, and readable.

Now, when your submission hits your receiving code, you can enjoy a loop again. (untested snippet)

```
$sql = "UPDATE switch SET status = CASE id WHEN" 
for ($x = 1; $x <= $maxBoxes; ++$x) {
    $sql .= sprintf(
        " %d THEN %d",
        $x, // %d
        (int)isset($_POST['boxes'][$x]) // %d
    );
}
$sql .= " END WHERE id BETWEEN $x AND $maxBoxes";
```

Because you are 100% in control of the dynamic data being fed to the query and you the placeholders in `sprintf()` are strongly typed, using a prepared statement can be avoided -- not that there is anything wrong with using a prepared statement (I merely chose not use one).

Perhaps the only thing not mentioned is: How are you going to determine that a submission was made when a submission includes no checkboxes (in your code)?  You are submitting every time a checkbox is toggled.  So if on the first submission, a checkbox is ticked, then that checkbox is unticked, the second submission will not trigger an UPDATE to the database.  To prevent this, you may want send a hidden value from the form so that you have something to confirm a submission.  (The `$_POST` superglobal array is always declared; you cannot determine anything by checking if it `isset()`.)